# Problem adding shell to new user

Tags: command-line

After adding a new user. It's shell is not added to /bin/bash itstead it is added to /bin/sh i have to change the shell for every new user I add. If there is any way a new user added should be given shell /bin/bash

Comment: What procedure are you using to add a new user?

Comment: I am using adduser command ex adduser username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the file `/etc/adduser.conf` contain a line with

```
DSHELL=/bin/bash
```

that is the default on Ubuntu.

Comment: thanx... i m checking

Answer (score 0):

I think the commande you are looking for is

```
dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

...as per this page : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh

Comment: Thanx it is helpfull